# java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (No available solution is working)

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, ubuntu, jdbc

I'm trying to create a JDBC application using Java and MySQL in **Eclipse IDE** and **Ubuntu 20.04** OS.

I'm getting the very common error while connecting to database that is "java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)" and I've tried every possible solution from stack overflow answers, youtube videos, articles, etc. but **nothing seems to work**.

**The error:**

[image]

**My java code:**

```java
package jdbcDemo;
import java.sql.*;

public class jdbcConnect {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jdbcDemo";
        String user = "root";
        String pswd = "1234";
        
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pswd);
        
        if(con == null) {
            System.out.println("Connection not established");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Connection established");
        }
    }

}
```

**Users in my database:**

[image]

**Databse information:**

[image]

Connection details (screenshots of mysql workbench):

[image]
[image]

I'm trying to access database through user **"root"** which has password **"1234"** and plugin is **"mysql_native_password"**.
I'm trying to make connection with **jdbcDemo** database which has **student** table.

I'm able to successfully access and manipulate database using the same user and password through **CLI and Workbench** but getting the same error again and again in **JDBC**.

**Some of the solutions that I've tried till now that didn't work:**

- Creating new user with all privileges
- re installing mysql server
- creating database via mysql workbench
- changing plugin of the users
- tried all different ways to write the url
- different types of connections (tci/ip, local socket/pipe)

All the solutions are either **outdated, not working or specific to windows** operating system.

Please suggest some solutions to solve this issue in Ubuntu 20.04 or different alternatives to do this task (remote databse, etc.)

**Thanks in advance !**

Comment: Try `Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();`

Comment: you might have a wrong plugin version

Comment: they recommend newInstance() call on the class loader https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary that is also causing the same error, that even shows it's deprecatde

Comment: @MarianP I'm using mysql 8.0.28 and mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar

Comment: Could be SSL. Try to remove SSL for testing, then try with code you have. Also, try to put user/pass in connection string, for testing purposes, and use "GetConnection" only with one parameter.

Answer (score 1):

In application.properties, add this statement:
`server.port = 8034` in case you've got some other application running that might be useing port 8080.
This helped me with this problem, took me several hours to find this solution.
Hope it helps someone.

Comment: There is only a main class in the question. Why should application.proprties be relevant?

Comment: Ahh, missed that bit, just ended up here after searching for a solution to my problem and thought this might help someone else who ended up here. My bad, maybe I should remove it?

Answer (score 0):

try to do this

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'username'@'localhost';


GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'username'@'127.0.0.1';
```

Answer (score 0):

Execute this sql statement:

```
update mysql.user set host = '%' where user = 'root' and host = 'localhost';
flush privileges;
```

And try again. It worked for me in a similar situation. Good luck!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

That's because of the password, try to change the symbols of your password.

I got the error when introducing some symbols like '€'

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to connect to a containerized database, **you may have a local SQL server running already on port 3306** - especially if you've just installed `mysql` locally.

You can check this by running:

```bash
sudo service mysql status # Linux
brew services info mysql  # Mac
```

If this is the case, your Spring application may invisibly be connecting to the default `mysql` instance on your machine, rather than your containerized database.

To stop the default `mysql` instance,

```bash
sudo service mysql stop  # Linux
brew services stop mysql # Mac
```

To disable auto-start,

```bash
sudo systemctl disable mysql                                      # Linux
launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.mysql.mysqld.plist # Mac
```

You can confirm nothing else is running on port 3306 by `telnet`-ing it:

```bash
telnet localhost 3306
```

Restart your Docker container and try and connect.